# Change Bitmap Drawable in LayerListDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

Here's the simplified version of my LayerList. It has a bitmap in an item to prevent scaling. I want to change the drawable of this bitmap programmatically. Is there a way to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item" 
        android:left="165dp" 
        android:top="245dp" >
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/bitmap" 
            android:src="@drawable/tag_de_01"
            android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I tried the following without success:

```
Resources res = getResources();
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_list_drawable);

Drawable newDrawable = (Drawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.something);

// works, but scales the image because the drawable of the item is set instead the one of the bitmap
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item, newDrawable);

// doesn't work at all
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.bitmap, newDrawable);
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Can someone help?

Comment: Were you able to come up with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Cast newDrawable to BitmapDrawable (assuming that it is one, of course), and you can use BitmapDrawable.setGravity the same way you use the android:gravity attribute in your xml to prevent scaling

Comment: What if I just want to change the SRC attribute?, How would you change the SRC attribute of R.id.bitmap bitmap?

Comment: it's actually a longer process to do it that way since you can't just update the source attribute.  the src attribute in xml is just a convenience...in all cases you have to decode the resource into a new Bitmap object and wrap it in a Drawable whether that is done for you by the framework or you write the code yourself.  have a look at the LayerDrawable and BitmapDrawable class documents to see what functionality is available to you.